# How to prevent modal popup asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using javascript modal in my asp.net project. I am calling it from dinamicly created asp.net buttons in code behind with this code ;

Code Behind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "$(function() { mesInfo(); });", true);
```

And HTML

```
 <script>   

    function mesInfo() {
        $('#message-box-info').modal('show');
    }    


</script>
```

Page working normally and calls modal when user click those dinamicly created asp.net buttons.
Problem is when user refresh page or use browser back button after calling modal once, modal pops again anyway. How can I prevent this. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Instead of invoking the modal using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in code behind.

you can add the event listener using Jquery

say
     is your button, your jquery event would be like

```
$('.button').live('click',function(){
  $('#message-box-info').modal('show');
});
```

here '.button' is the class i have considered for the button.
Hope this will help